# How to check if a string contain consecutive characters in a vector using R

Tags: r, string, grepl

I have the following vector of characters and minimum threshold.

```
ref_vector <- c("R", "H", "K")
min_thres <- 5
```

What I want to do is given a string, and check if that string contains any consecutive characters within `ref_vector` and with the amount less than equal to `min_thres`.

So this is the example of string and the answer:

```
x1 <- "GMRRRRRRRS"    # Answ: True
#        *****
#         *****
#          *****


x2 <- "GKRKRRHRRS"    # Answ: True
#       *****
#        *****
#         *****
#          *****


x3 <- "GKRKARHQRS"    # Answ: False
#       *** ** *
```

The length and content of the input string and `ref_vector` can be varied.
How can I achieve that with R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `grepl()` here with an appropriate regex pattern:

```r
x <- c("GMRRRRRRRS", "GKRKRRHRRS", "GKRKARHQRS")
ref_vector <- c("R", "H", "K")
regex = paste0("[", paste(ref_vector, collapse=""), "]{5}")  # [RHK]{5}
grepl(regex, x)

[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```